# python openpyxl.load_workbook(r"mypath")

Tags: python, excel, load, openpyxl

i want to use this piece of code openpyxl.load_workbook(r"mypath") but the only difference is that mypath is a varialbe path i change everytime depending on a loop of different folders.

```
PathsList = []
for folderName, subFolders, fileNames in os.walk              
                fileNamesList.append(os.path.basename(fileName))
                PathsList.append(os.path.abspath(fileName))

or i in range(len(fileNamesList)):
    j = 1
    while j < len(fileNamesList):
        if(first3isdigit(fileNamesList[i])) == (first3isdigit(fileNamesList[j])):
            if(in_fileName_DOORS in str(fileNamesList[i]) and in_fileName_TAF in str(fileNamesList[j])):
                mypath = PathsList[i]
        File = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'mypath ')
                wsFile = File.active
```

mypath is not readable as a vairable , is there's any solution!
Edit 1:i thought also about

```
File = openpyxl.load_workbook(exec(r'%s' % (mypath))
```

but couldn't since exec can't be inside brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
File = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'mypath ')
```

Tries to pass the raw string `'mypath '` as an argument to the `load_workbook` method.

If you want to pass the contents of the `mypath` variable to the method, you should remove the apostrophe and the r tag.

```
File = openpyxl.load_workbook(mypath)
```

This is basic python synthax. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html).

Please let me know if this is what you needed.

Edit:
If the slashes are a concern you can do the following:

```
File = openpyxl.load_workbook(mypath.replace('\\','/')
```

Comment: it didn't work , it needs this r before mypath 
what i am searching for is how to 
File = openpyxl.load_workbook(r mypath)
insteadof 
File = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\spam\spam\spam\text.xlsm')

Comment: @MahmoudElnahal I have edited my answer. Let me know if it works. Also, add `print(mypath)` before this line and edit your question, so we can see what filepaths are formed.